# Why dynamically created user controls disappear when controls are not doing full postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

Based on my current understandings, when you have an UpdatePanel control there is no full postback. Therefore if I dynamically add custom user controls and they have UpdatePanels that are updated in their code they shouldnt disappear from the page they are loaded into, right? Apparently not. I made a simple project to test and still my dynamic controls disappear when clicked even though they should not be triggering a full postback. I have an aspx page that loads the controls:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TESTmultipleScriptManagerControls.aspx.cs" Inherits="myPlayground.TESTmultipleScriptManagerControls" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TESTcontrol1 temp = LoadControl("TESTcontrol1.ascx") as TESTcontrol1;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(temp);
        TESTcontrol1 temp2 = LoadControl("TESTcontrol1.ascx") as TESTcontrol1;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(temp2);

    }
```

And a simple user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TESTcontrol1.ascx.cs" Inherits="myPlayground.TESTcontrol1" %>
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

With the following code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Any ideas on why the controls are disappearing even though there shouldnt be a postback triggering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OK based on my current understandings, when you have an UpdatePanel
>   control there is no full postback.

Postbacks triggered from UpdatePanels always execute the full page life-cycle. All the events are triggered normally. It makes no difference whether you use an UpdatePanel or not. Every time you add a control programmatically you need to re-add it on every postback.

[Read this post](http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/), it may help you understand a bit better what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

By End of the **[Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)** all the controls generated at `Runtime/Compile Time` will be `Disposed`.

Below are the Page Events. Please set the `BreakPoint` on each Event and you can figure out that on each `Asynchronous/Synchronous Request`, all these `Page Events` are being executed.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
}

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}

protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreLoad(e);
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoadComplete(e);
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
}

protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);
}
```

You need to populate them on each `Page Init event` in order to persist `Viewstate`, also events for controls added inside an update panel during button clicks do not seems to get registered until the next `Postback`. My suggestion is to keep a list of what you have added dynamically, and store it in a session variable