# How can I add a new dynamic control on button click?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dynamic

When I click btnGDynamicCont I want to load the first set of controls, then on each further click of that button, add a new control (textbox) alongside the other ones, so each time it is clicked I am adding a new textbox across state.

Do you know where I should add the creation of the new textbox in order to keep it after each postback?

```
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Generated"]) == "true")
            GenerateDynamicControls();

    }

    public void GenerateDynamicControls()
    {
        TextBox txtDynamic = new TextBox();
        txtDynamic.ID = "txtDynamic";
        txtDynamic.Text = "Dynamic TextBox";
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(txtDynamic);

        TextBox txtDynamic2 = new TextBox();
        txtDynamic2.ID = "txtDynamic2";
        txtDynamic2.Text = "Dynamic Textbox";
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(txtDynamic2);

    }

    protected void btnGDynamicCont_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Generated"]) != "true")
        {
            GenerateDynamicControls();
            ViewState["Generated"] = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<h2>Controls are already exist in page</h2>");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls are usually recreated at the Page_Load method.  For more information, please refer to the [Dynamically Created Controls in ASP.NET](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx) article.

Comment: The ones that I am currently adding are in the page_load, the issue is that if I don't want to add controls that are pre-define and instead add one new instance each time I click (which I do) then it creates the first one and never creates a second control. I have tried it without an ID etc. in the hope that it will keep creating controls on the page but it doesn't.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this your comment :(.  Anyway, if you want previously created controls to appear on the page, you should recreate them at every request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link where a very similar issue is addressed.

[unable to add more than one server control dynamically in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562117/unable-to-add-more-than-one-server-control-dynamically-in-asp-net/19562431#19562431)

Everytime a postback happens, you should recreate the already existing controls(dynamically added) in your page_load event and the new controls are to be created in the button_click event.

Use some logic to generate ids for the controls for the viewstate to be maintained. VIEWSTATE will be taken care automatically if the ids of the controls generated before and after postback are the same.

One way to keep track of the number of textboxes is to store the count in session.

Comment: I have come a little closer now with the code below, I still have a couple of problems that I can't resolve 1) the first time around 2 boxes are added 2) (this ones weird) the textboxes are kept not only during postback, but also after page refresh, browser shutdown, debugging stopped, different browsers etc. how is that happening?

Comment: Yeah, in the example quoted 2 rows are added by default.. you can remove them if required. those were static rows in aspx