# How to generate table rows when clicking a button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, multiple-columns

I want to generate a UI dynamically like

Initially a table will be displayed with 3 columns and 5 rows. In the three columns user will enter a values if the user needs additional  there will be a button called add more and when user clicks on that button a new row should be added to that existing column. user can remove any column just clicking on another button called remove column.and i need to save all these values to in table to the database .....how can i achieve this?awaiting your reply nation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach used in the below example if you want the table to be built on your own and you dont want to use Gridview.

You can create the controls dynamically using the Syatem.Web.UI namespace, but please note that ASP.net is stateless and you will have to recreate the controls across postbacks.
View state will be maintained automatically if you use the same logic to generate the same ids again dynamically.

[unable to add more than one server control dynamically in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562117/unable-to-add-more-than-one-server-control-dynamically-in-asp-net/19562431#19562431)

hope that helps.