# How to get the selected value of a <select> element on the code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have this element:

```
<select name="activity" id="activity" required class="span12" runat="server">
</select>
```

I need to pass its value to a stored procedure, but "activity.Value" returns nothing, and Request["activity"] returns the whole list of options contained in the element (its children elements)!

CodeBehind:

```
this.sqlLog.InsertParameters["Activity"].DefaultValue = Request["activity"]; //Returns whole list of options
this.sqlLog.InsertParameters["Activity"].DefaultValue = activity.Value; //Returns nothing
```

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention my select elements are populated via AJAX. So yea, at the time the server side code runs it's empty, hence the errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using as below if it is a asp.net dropdownlist control.

```
 activity.SelectedValue
```

Update:

Use `activity.Items[activity.SelectedIndex]`  if it is a HTML server control

Comment: I can't. It says 'it doesn't contain a definition for SelectedValue'

Comment: activity.SelectedItem.Text??

Comment: There's no SelectedItem, theres SelectedIndex though

Comment: Apologies, i thought yours is a asp:dropdown control. You have to use activity.Items[activity.SelectedIndex]

Comment: It does makes sense! But now I'm getting an error saying the index is out of range :(

Comment: why dont you try having a "value" attribute for your options , and get the selected value using activity.value??

Comment: there is a value attribute in each option, but still 'activity.Value' returns me nothing

Comment: One more point, when none of the items are selected, your selected index may be -1, and you might get a index out of range error. Incude a check to verify the value of selected index before using it to access the value

Comment: I debugged it and the selected item is always 0, regardless of what's selected on the select element. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are addign the options dynamically to your select control. And dynamically created controls will not be available across postbacks. you have to recreate them. and that is why you always get 0, as your options are not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562117/unable-to-add-more-than-one-server-control-dynamically-in-asp-net/19562431#19562431 this should help